# OData Dynamics - Last request within batch request is given error

Tags: https, dynamics-crm, odata, batch-processing

Problem: last request within batch request is given error

```
"code":"0x80048d19","message":"Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'' ...
```

I'm trying to use the $batch method for updating records in CRM via API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api

I build the request payload as the documentation refer - without using *changeset*, since my requests within the batch are independent from each other and in case of error I would like the process to continue.

In the header:

```
Authorization: Bearer XX
Prefer: odata.continue-on-error
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_bi20230503-17-47-26"
```

The payload (example with 2 requests)

```
--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26
Content-Type: application/http 
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

PATCH https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447183-E6FB-EA11-A813-000D3AD9183C) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "tv_customerhealthscore": "6"
}
--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26
Content-Type: application/http 
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

PATCH https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447FD1-0B2C-ED11-9DB1-002248A01150) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "tv_customerhealthscore": "0"
}
--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26--
```

The response that I get:

```
--batchresponse_5484dc4c-fdf6-459e-af7d-324d7e529c06
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
OData-Version: 4.0
Location: https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447183-E6FB-EA11-A813-000D3AD9183C)
OData-EntityId: https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447183-E6FB-EA11-A813-000D3AD9183C)


--batchresponse_5484dc4c-fdf6-459e-af7d-324d7e529c06
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
REQ_ID: b01e8127-b7a0-4383-b501-f55577c55675
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0

{"error":{"code":"0x80048d19","message":"Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'', For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293  ---->  InnerException : System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.\r\n   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)\r\n   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightInputContext.CreateTextReader(Stream messageStream, Encoding encoding)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightInputContext..ctor(ODataMessageInfo messageInfo, ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Json.ODataJsonFormat.CreateInputContext(ODataMessageInfo messageInfo, ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.ODataMessageReader.ReadFromInput[T](Func`2 readFunc, ODataPayloadKind[] payloadKinds)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)."}}
--batchresponse_5484dc4c-fdf6-459e-af7d-324d7e529c06--
```

And this behaves like this for any number of requests I put in batch. This is, the last request allows throws this error.

Already checked:

- The two records are from the same entity
- They both exists in the CRM.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a bug with the Batch API. I was able to find a work around and do a dummy GET for one of the entities in the Batch request at the end and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Try this:

```
--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26
Content-Type: application/http 
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

PATCH https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447183-E6FB-EA11-A813-000D3AD9183C) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "tv_customerhealthscore": "6"
}
--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26
Content-Type: application/http 
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

PATCH https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447FD1-0B2C-ED11-9DB1-002248A01150) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "tv_customerhealthscore": "0"
}

--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26
Content-Type: application/http 
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

GET https://XXXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(FE447FD1-0B2C-ED11-9DB1-002248A01150) HTTP/1.1

--batch_bi20230503-17-47-26--
```

Comment: Thank you for this - was pulling out my hair.

Comment: By the way, any GET at the end (something that doesn't require passing JSON) gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

This API leverages Microsoft's OData library which requires [CRLF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF) line endings. Some clients (ex.: Postman) use LF line endings and will cause the deserialization error `System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.`.

If you are unable to use CRLF line endings, add 2 non-CRLF line endings to the end of the request payload, which will solve this specific deserialization error.

The [public $batch documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api#batch-requests) has been updated to clarify the CRLF requirement.